# Can someone help me understand this interaction?

Tags: meaning, readings, conversations

This is an interaction that I saw while reading Pokemon Special.

The context is a gym battle between Platinum and Suzuna. When Platinum defeats Suzuna's first Pokemon, she explains how her Emperte has an advantage due to typing.

Suzuna asks あれ? なんか「 自分はじぶんまったくやられていません」 、 みたいな感じだよね?

Confused about the question, Platinum asks そ、それはどういうこと. . . 、As she is asking this, a seed that she is unaware of is descending toward Emperte. The seed was shot before Suzuna's Pokemon fainted.

When the seed hits Emperte on the head and knocks it out, Suzuna responds こういう こと。

The main thing preventing me from understanding this is the scentence in quotations. I can't tell what やら would mean here since it seems to have various uses. I only understand that Suzuna is asking about an impression.

I also noticed that こういうこと。rhymes with どういうこと. Is this supposed to be intentional or is it only coincidence?

Answer (score 2):

This やら is actually from やる in it's passive form (やられる) + ていません, which in the end gives you やられていません. The word やる has lots of different meanings, but from the context, I'd say it's something like 'not being done' or 'not being finished' or 'not being beaten'.

So, this Suzuna character says something like:

> Huh? It's kind of like, 'I'm not really being beaten,' isn't it?

To which the second character, Platinum, asks:

> Huh, what do you mean...

And Suzuna answers:

> I mean this.

Comment: I'm aware of the conjugation but I appreciate it. What does て do there? On J-talk, it is categorized as ing but from the way you formatted it, that does not seem the be the purpose.

Comment: It's not always the gerund. For example, you can say something like 彼はもう死んでる ('He is dead') and it doesn't mean the person is continuously dying. 〜ている can describe an ongoing action, or a current state that's the result of a past action. Here the state 'not being defeated' is the result of the previous fight with Platinum, whoever that is.